# Couchdb -> Using the Couchbeam

Tags: erlang, couchdb

How to create temporary view and getting view results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CouchBeam does not, should not and probably will not support temporary views.

Temporary views really have awful performance and the CouchDB devs recommend against it's use except for trying things out in a database with just a few docs.

Comment: Thanks! Then how to create a query without creating design view for the db by couchbeam, for example: return all docs when field (key) "count" is 34 to 45 or something key:value equal to "id_smth":"45" and etc. And each new query isn't similar with the previous (range counts or id_smth changes).

Comment: You simply should not. If you wish to use CouchDB you use design documents. Temporary views have awful performance and your code will be dead slow once you have some data.

Comment: If you need complex queries you connect CouchDB to a search database such as lucene or elasticsearch.